# Can I use a DockerFile as a script?

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

We would like to leverage the excellent catalogue of DockerFiles on DockerHub, but the team is not in a position to use Docker.

Is there any way to run a DockerFile as if it were a shell script against a machine?

For example, if I chose to run the Docker container `ruby:2.4.1-jessie` against a server running only Debian Jessie, I'd expect it to ignore the `FROM` directive but be able to set the environment from `ENV` and run the `RUN` commands from this Dockerfile: [Github docker-library/ruby:2.4.1-jessie](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/627e55f6a1ec8d63b5c3671e25c70bdae412ef56/2.4/jessie/Dockerfile#L3-L77)

Comment: Please provide an example Dockerfile and what should happen as a result of running it

Comment: I guess you could copy `RUN` commands and manually do other steps. But apart from that, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

A dockerfile assumes to be executed in an empty container or an image on which it builds (using FROM). The knowledge about the environment (specifically the file system and all the installed software) is important and running something similar outside of docker might have side effects because files are at places where no files are expected.

I wouldn't recomend it